# Default applications

Tags: service-application

Not sure why Managed Metadata shows as default application thru central admin. I even ran following in powershell `Set-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Identity "Metadata Service Application Proxy" -DefaultProxyGroup`

But when I run this code I see zero.

```
$gt = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site http://Portal.company.com/sales
write-host $gt.TermStores.Count
```

However, when I run the code code in another farm like QC or Test then it shows 1.